# Changing opacity of one form using a second form

Tags: c#, winforms

So I want my form2's `Trackbar` to change the opacity of my form1 but it doesn't seem to get the job done?

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

        frm1.Opacity = trackBar1.Value * 000.1d;

    }
}
```

Comment: You generate a new object `Form1 frm1` everytime you scroll. I think you want to change the opacity of an existing Form

Comment: It is an existing form, that's what my problem is.

Comment: trackBar_Scroll is an event. The function is called each time you scroll the bar. And each time you do `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();`. This generates a new Form1 everytime

Comment: **Form1 frm1 = new Form1();** creates a new instance with Form1's default values (default Opacity value equals 1) and naturally Form1's old opacity value is losing.

Comment: It's amazing how often this question or some variation thereof comes up. At least once a day. I guess it's time to write a canonical question and start closing them as duplicates of that one. Anyone know if that's already been done?

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing the opacity of *your* Form1, you are changing the opacity of a *new* Form1. You need to make sure you change the opacity of the form instance you want to change:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 form;

    public Form2(Form1 form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form = form;
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.Opacity = trackBar1.Value * 000.1d;
    }
  }
}
```

Then when you create Form2, pass the instance of Form1 you want to change. For example from a button in your Form1:

```
public void opacityChangeButton_Click(object sender , EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 opacityChangeForm = new Form2(this);
    opacityChangeForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new form everytime use the id of the existing form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do not create a new form: Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

        // Use name of original form
        whateverVariableyourCreateedForYourForm.Opacity = trackBar1.Value * 000.1d;

    }
}
```

Comment: How could you set value to Opacity property without an instance? It should be static but you didn't say anything about static. Am I wrong?